# JSON DateTime remove time in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have the following `DateTime` which has a value of: `"2017-01-27T00:00:00"`.

How can I remove the above date to return only the date without the time and without changing the format? i.e return `"2017-01-27"`

Comment: You need to convert to a `string`.

Comment: You can change the way properties are serialized with the proper attribute. Where does the `DateTime` value come from? Is it a property ?

Comment: In addition, do you know it will always be `-` as the separator? And obviously you want to return a string, yar?

Comment: @musefan that's the ISO8601 standard. The separator will *always* be `-`

Comment: @erbsoftware are you using JSON.NET or MVC's older serializer?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The separator can be whatever the f*** you want it to be. Requirements dictate that, and that is what I am looking for the OP to clear up

Comment: @musefan dates in Json follow the ISO8601 format. Of course, if business requirements state `Return the date in an unrecognizable format that will fail to parse outside our company without manual intervention` ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: What makes you think anyone needs to parse it? Sometimes I will have a ajax request return JSON and just put the string in the format I want to display it in, because there isn't a need to work with the value other than display it on the screen. Besides, I have seen plenty more questionable requirements from SO questions...

Comment: @erbsoftware Sorry for closing this as duplicate but I wanted to stop the flood of bad answers. The duplicate answers how to use a date-only format when using Json.NET, the most common case nowadays. If you use MVC's older (obsolete) serializer, there's bound to be another duplicate that explains how to do it

Comment: @musefan because JavaScript actually understands ISO8601? And because display formats are the job of the displaying page, not the API?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, OP has not tagged this Json.NET (just asp.net-mvc) so most likely they are not using Json.NET!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I explained this in a previous comment. There's a flood of bad answers. Pedro's answer at least provides the correct format. I'd gladly change the duplicate if the OP is using MVC's serializer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Again with the assumptions... who said anything about an API? Could just be a controller action that is used for ajax loading of data. Why bother giving the client the task of working out how to display a date, when you can just send back a string exactly how you want it displayed.

Comment: @musefan OK you win. World loses. JSON doesn't mean JSON anymore

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You work with the requirements you have, maybe you are right, maybe the OP *does* need to parse the date client-side. But to say it *has* to be done that way is way too restrictive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: So are you saying JSON doesn't support strings?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe?

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2017-01-27T00:00:00");
return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: A far better option is to tell the serializer to use that format. That's already possible with Json.NET and there are a lot of duplicates that explain this

Answer (score 0):

If you need some customization for the date, you can use `*name*.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')` to customize the result. See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` returns the *local* short date format.